# Does ConManClient2 have any prerequisites on WinCE6?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-ce, remote-debugging, platform-builder, corecon

I have created a Windows CE6 Image through Platform Builder, and I now want to develop c++ applications on this device with VS2005.

With Visual Studio 2005 comes ConManClient2, compiled for each patform, which can be placed onto the target platform to allow for remote degugging from VS.

On previous platforms, ones I haven't designed the OS for, this has worked without (too many) issues.

However, on this platform, when I run ConManClient2 (then CMAccept), each exe just returns with no message, and no action. And no remote connection is possible.

Apart from the 2 .dll's that come with ConManClient2, what else is required to allow these tools to run? Is there anything specific needed in the CE6 image? Any other configuration?

This image runs fine apart this, to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think conmanclient has much for requirements other than probably NDIS support (you could use depends or dumpbin to see everything).  Neither one produces any output or message, so the lack of any noticeable behavior is expected.  You could call clientshutdown.exe and that should create a guid-named folder in the same directory and a subsequent call to conmanclient2.exe will delete that folder.

Do you see anything out the device's debug port when you run it?

Comment: Calls the the client & shutdown certainly create & remove the folder as you describe, however VS2005 is unable to connect to this system from remote debugging. On previous systems, when conman was run, it produced a command line prompt indicating that it was waiting for a connection, this one does nothing. I thought possible it needed KITL, but apparently not. I cannot understand why these standalone files don't just work 'out of the box' as they claim to be able to do.

Comment: Are you using the same ConManClient2.exe that is on your development machine?  The versions must match.